# How to click javascript button html

Tags: vb.net

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc3fq.png
)

I was tried with this code but not invoke that button:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li")
        If elem.GetAttribute("id") = "Yes4gAccountMenu" Then
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
Next
```

It just focus on that button, not click it

Comment: `<li>` is not a button.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't "click it"?  What are you expecting to *happen* when you click an `<li>` element?

Comment: @AluanHaddad how about this code. where is my mistake sir .. For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
            If elem.GetAttribute("onclick") = "javascript:return onLeftMenuSubmit('doShowYes4GAccount');" Then
                elem.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this way.

```
For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allButtons
    If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") =  "Start" Then
        webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: make sure that this is button not <li> list element.

Comment: How about declaration of allButtons?

Comment: WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")

Comment: There is no element of 'button' in that page.. As i updates my question with image